# How to load API output into Python

Tags: python, api, search

I am using the twitter API search function through apigee.com/console/twitter and need a way to load the output of the search into a file that can be searched through a python script that I have. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output is json you can use `json.loads()`

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
>>> json.loads('"\\"foo\\bar"')
u'"foo\x08ar'
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> io = StringIO('["streaming API"]')
>>> json.load(io)
[u'streaming API']
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json